# Rspec: how to expect mock to receive a method in an `each` loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I need to test something like this (simplified):

```
class Event
  def self.charge_unpaid_events
    unpaid_events.each do |event|
      event.charge
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

I'm using FactoryGirl and have a test like this:

```
event = FactoryGirl.create(:event)
event.should receive(:charge)
Event.charge_unpaid_events
```

This fails. I've run into this before, and my understanding is that within the context of the each loop, the block parameter `event` is a different object than my mock object `event`. I've gotten around this in the past by ensuring there's only one event instance and using `Event.any_instance.should receive...`, but that won't work in the context I'm trying to test right now (for other reasons I won't go into).

Is there a smarter way around this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from that small code snippet but I'm going to guess that `unpaid_events` is a `scope` or similar query. Additionally, `Event` is some sort of DB backed "traditional" Rails-y model.

With those assumptions and given the way the method is currently written, I would normally say this should be an acceptance spec. With that type of spec, I would not mock anything. However, it sounds like `charge` may have some far reaching and undesired side effects.

If that is truly the case, then without changing your code, you would need to stub `Event.unpaid_events` to return a collection of mocks. Generally, stubbing the object under test is a code smell and points to an object that is doing too much.

Here's what such a spec may look like:

```
it "charges all unpaid events" do
  mock_events = [ double(Event, charge: true), double(Event, charge: true) ]
  allow(Event).to receive(:unpaid_events).and_return(mock_events)

  Event.charge_unpaid_events

  mock_events.all?{ |mock| expect(mock).to have_received(:charge) }
end
```

The first refactor I would probably make is to inject the events that should be charged, with a default of the scope. I probably would at the same time only charge those events that were unpaid:

```
class Event
  def self.charge_unpaid_events(events = unpaid_events)
    events.select(&:unpaid?)
          .each(&:charge)
  end
end

it "charges all the unpaid events" do
  paid_events = [ double(Event, unpaid: false), double(Event, unpaid: false) ]
  unpaid_events = [
    double(Event, unpaid: true, charge: true),
    double(Event, unpaid: true, charge: true)
  ]
  mock_events = paid_events + unpaid_events

  Event.charge_unpaid_events mock_events

  unpaid_events.all?{ |event| expect(event).to have_received(:charge) }
end

it "does not charge paid events" do
  # Normally testing 'not' conditions is more work than necessary, however for a
  # simple method such as this; plus the fact that charging things that are
  # `paid` can have more drastic consequences; I would argue this deserves a spec
  paid_events = [ double(Event, unpaid: false), double(Event, unpaid: false) ]
  unpaid_events = [
    double(Event, unpaid: true, charge: true),
    double(Event, unpaid: true, charge: true)
  ]
  mock_events = paid_events + unpaid_events

  Event.charge_unpaid_events mock_events

  paid_events.all?{ |event| expect(event).not_to have_received(:charge) }
end
```

At this point I would call into question the job of `Event` to both be responsible for managing what gets charged and how something should be charged. I would probably investigate moving those to external service classes to keep charging responsibilities out of a simple event object.